# In Eclipse package explorer, some files are not visible?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a file named saveFile.txt in my java project
[image: seen here]

This is my project explorer view. As you can see, the file is not visible.
[image: project explorer]

I tried disabling all filters

> menu > filters > deselect all

still the saveFile.txt is not visible.
How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Click project -> F5/Refresh

Comment: as @RajeevSreedharan suggested to you, try to refresh the project, sometimes eclipse don't work very well

Comment: Thanks. That worked!!